# How to do the function like shooting in Space Invader game?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to do a function that similar to the shooting function in the Space Invader game for school assignment, the problem is I haven't learned css, canvas, I have seen many tutorials using it but I can't apply it in my assignment.

Is there any way to do the function with svg elements?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Did you tried something? Can you post the code of what you did?

Comment: Please add the jsfiddle to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't spoon feed, but I'll show you how to when click have an html element move like an animation.. the concept is simply setting an interval and changing the offset of said element

```js
//this spawns an element and runs it
function myMove(){var pos=0
  var myDiv=document.createElement('div')
  myDiv.className="animate"
  document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0].appendChild(myDiv)
  var s=setInterval(()=>{
    if(pos>=230-55){clearInterval(s)}
    else{pos++; myDiv.style.top=pos+"px"}
  },5)
}
document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0].onclick=myMove
```

```css
.container {
  width: 60px;
  height: 230px;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
  float: left;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
}
.animate {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><div class ="container"></div></a>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to understand it